# make element stick to bottom of patent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I want to place an element to its parent bottom. I can't set its `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` because my parent div may be scrolled(overview-y) by zooming or in smaller displays. I want the element to be stuck at the bottom of the parent if the parent other elements do not exceed the widow height, otherwise this child be the last in scrolling.

[image: see image]

how is that possible? should I use js or is there anyway to do it by css?

tnx

Comment: the answer is in the question. `position: absolute; bottom: 0`

Comment: It's hard to fix images. Please show the relevant HTML and CSS instead of images.

Comment: use footer in that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a child content container with `min-height` set to match the parent's height. Put enough padding on the bottom of the content element for your footer and use `position:absolute` to attach your footer to the bottom.

See the snippet below.

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.grey').toggleClass('big');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.content .grey {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: grey;
}

.content .grey.big {
  height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: grey;
}

.content footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 5px 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
</p>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <div class="grey"></div>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

```css
/**
 * Demo Styles
 */

html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
  min-height:1000px;
}

.demo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <h1>CSS “Always on the bottom” Footer</h1>

  <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>

  <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>
  <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>
  <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>

  <p>If you know the height of the footer, then you should set it explicitly, and set the bottom padding of the footer’s parent element to be the same value (or larger if you want some spacing).</p>

  <p>This is to prevent the footer from overlapping the content above it, since it is being removed from the document flow with <code>position: absolute;</code>.</p>
  
</div>

<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
```